# Failure to return to calling function from NSURLSession delegate without killing the task

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, nsurlsession

I'm using Swift in Xcode 6.2 (beta) but had the same problem on the 6.1 release version.  I'm trying to use NSURLSession and believe I have it set up correctly (see code below).  The problem is that I have a delegate setup to deal with a redirect happening through the code.  I actually need to capture the cookies prior to the final redirection and I'm doing this through the delegate:

`func URLSession(_:NSURLSession, task:NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection:NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest:NSURLRequest, completionHandler:(NSURLRequest!) -> Void )`

This works and I'm able to execute code successfully and capture the cookies I need.  The problem is that I need to add `task.cancel()` at the end of the function or else it never seems to complete and return to the delegator (parent?) function.  Because of this I lose the results from the redirect URL (although in my current project it is inconsequential).  The strange thing is that this was working for a while and seemingly stopped.  I don't believe I entered any code that changed it, but something had to happen.  Below is the relevant code.

NSURLSession Function:

```
func callURL (a: String, b: String) -> Void {
    // Define the URL
    var url = NSURL(string: "https://mycorrecturl.com");

    // Define the request object (via string)
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    // Use default configuration
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    // Create the NSURLSession object with default configuration, and self as a delegate (so calls delegate method)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    // Change from default GET to POST (needed to call URL properly)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // Construct my parameters to send in with the URL
    var params = ["a":a, "b":b] as Dictionary<String, String>

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        // Do some other stuff after delegate has returned...
    })
    task.resume()
    return
}
```

The delegate code:

```
func URLSession(_:NSURLSession, task:NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection:NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest:NSURLRequest, completionHandler:(NSURLRequest!) -> Void ) {
    // Check Cookies
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://mycorrecturl.com")
    var all = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(willPerformHTTPRedirection.allHeaderFields, forURL: url!)

    // Get the correct cookie
    for cookie:NSHTTPCookie in all as [NSHTTPCookie] {
        if cookie.name as String == "important_cookie" {
            NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
    task.cancel()
}
```

It used to return to the calling function without calling task.cancel().  Is there anything that looks wrong with the code that would cause it to just hang in the delegate function if task.cancel() isn't called?

**Edit:** What code would I add to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not canceling the request, your `willPerformHTTPRedirection` should call the `completionHandler`. As the documentation says, this `completionHandler` parameter is:

> A block that your handler should call with either the value of the request parameter, a modified URL request object, or `NULL` to refuse the redirect and return the body of the redirect response.

Comment: The completionHandler is being called and executing.  When it gets to the end of the completionHandler it just seems to stop executing code instead of returning to the task.  I've tried 'task.resume()' instead of 'task.cancel()', which didn't work.  Do I need to call a new'_.dataTaskWithRequest(newRequest, completionHandler: {...' from within the delegate completionHandler?  I saw the documentation but it is unclear to me what it is refering to when it says the 'handler should call.'  Should call what?

Comment: You say that you are calling the `completionHandler`, but your delegate code shown in your question does not show you doing that. Can you please edit your question, showing us your current implementation of `willPerformHTTPRedirection`?

Comment: I think there is something I don't understand, all the code is being called up to and including 'task.cancel()'.  Is there something else I'm supposed to do besides call task.cancel() to get into the dataTaskWithRequest completionHandler?  I'm confused by what code I would add to the above to make it complete the completionHandler that is set up in the callURL function.You say my delegate code doesn't show me calling the completionHandler - thats really my question, what am I missing to do that?

Comment: @jackfrost2199 Generally, you'd have a line at the end of that method that says `completionHandler(nil)` or `completionHandler(newRequest)` or `completionHandler(someOtherRequest)` where `someOtherRequest` is some `NSMutableURLRequest` you create. But that `completionHandler` parameter is a closure, and you have to call it.

Comment: Ok great, I think that makes sense to me.  Closures are still new to me.

Comment: BTW for anyone having similar issues, completionHAndler(nil) worked exactly as I needed.  For some reason the first 10 times or so I ran this it automatically jumped back and so I was expecting that as the default behavior.  Not sure if I changed something that was causing this to happen without realizing it or if something was being glitchy.